# Arch dual monitor: xrandr incorrectly identifies my monitors

Tags: xrandr, multi-monitor

I am trying to setup a dual monitor environment on the Arch linux (4.14 kernel, Xorg and KDE run without any errors). 
My machine uses Intel i5-6500 (Skylake) with onboard HD530 graphics. the motherboard is ASUS Z170M with VGA, DVI and HDMI ports.
I want to connect two 1280x1024 monitors, one via DVI and one via VGA.

When I launch `$ xrandr -q` it shows that I have `DP1` (display port), `HDMI1`, `HDMI2` and `VIRTUAL1` outputs, which is totally incorrect. `DP1` is the active one (VGA monitor).

I tried to manipulate `HDMI1`, `HDMI2` and `VIRTUAL1` outputs hoping that one of them is my DVI output, but monitor stayed black and `xrandr` reported that these outputs are disconnected/do not support modes.

What do I do? Seeing that my outputs are not detected correctly I am not sure what should I write into `xorg.conf`

Edit:
Both monitors work during boot, UEFI setup menu and bootloader - they display the same picture.
The first monitor is Samsung SyncMaster 971p (only 1 DVI port) and the seconds is LG FLATRON L1950SQ (only 1 VGA port). 
Samsung (DVI) shuts down right after bootloader even if it is the only connected monitor. It works fine with other computers.